# Is it possible to find an element in a Vec<T> and remove it?

Tags: vector, rust

In Rust, is there an in built function for finding and removing elements of a vector, both simultaneously and as separate actions?

For example:

```
for f in factors {
    if f in list {
        list.remove(f);
    }
}
```

Currently, the rust documentation is still a tad confusing, so while my search as shown up nothing, I feel like there is a good chance someone else may have found it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The example can be written as:

```
let mut list = (0..10).collect::<Vec<u32>>();
list.retain(|element| element % 2 == 0);
assert_eq!(&list[..], &[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]);
```

The relevant documentation can be found here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html

Comment: Ah interesting, it shifts the focus which is probably why finding it might be difficult.

Answer (score 6):

You could always use an `into_iter()` to destructure the Vec into an iterator, `filter(..)` that for the element and `collect()` into a new Vec:

```
list.into_iter().filter(|e| !factors.contains(e)).collect();
```

You may need to specify the type of collect (which should be Vec<*T*> where *T* is the type of your element) unless you bind it into a variable of the right type.

Edit: Following A.B.'s advice, you could also write

```
list.retain(|e| !factors.contains(e))
```

Note that both would be within O(L × F) where L is the len of `list` and F the len of `factors`. For small L and/or F, this will be fine. Otherwise it may be better to convert factors into a HashSet first.

Answer (score 5):

There is no simultaneous "find and remove" method, that I know of.
Vec has:

- [remove](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove) is the general method to remove an element and shift all the ones that follow to fill the gap
- [swap_remove](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap_remove) remove this element and replace it with the last (avoids all the shifting, so it's generally quicker)
- [pop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.pop) removes the last element (very efficient, might not be what you need if you want to remove an element in the middle of the Vec)

you could do something like:

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
// iterate through the vector and return the position for the
// first element == 2. If something is found bind it to the name
// index
if let Some(index) = v.iter().position(|&i| i == 2) {
    v.remove(index); // remove the element at the position index (2)
}

println!("{:?}", v); // prints [1, 3]
```